# UIView accessibility issue

Tags: iphone, uiview, accessibility, addsubview

I've developed an iPhone App and most of it is accessible but I have an issue with one thing I do.

When the user clicks the settings button in the App (it has a main menu with a bunch of buttons for various Applications) I add a UIView on the top and and darken the background screen. Unfortunately for a blind person this UIView doesn't become "active", ie they are still navigating around the background screen.

I initially added the UIView using `addSubview:` and then tried `insertSubview: atIndex:` but neither have operated as expected.

Edit: Further information there are text fields and a button on this screen, perhaps I could instead make one of them active or something?? No idea how I would do this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `becomeFirstResponder`? It makes the control receiving this message active and the receiver of input. For UITextView etc. it brings up the keyboard.

Comment: That worked kinda as I've been trying. Just as a side note I had to use resignFirstResponder as at the stage I remove it its still retained in memory and a blind person is kept on a non display screen. Not 100% sure if it is released would this be the same case as technically it would probably be retained by the accessibility framework and releasing it would have no effect. Also on displaying the view the user doesn't get notified. I might set the first label to be the first responder...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you are saying, but I thought there may be problem with the view added on the top.

Do one thing, if you added the view using interface builder then select the view and click on Layout menu in the Menu bar and select "Send to Back".

or else if you add that through code, then write code as

`[self.view sendSubViewToBack:addedView];`

Regards,

Satya

Comment: That would probably be the same as inserting it at the top index. Also there is an issue where when I remove the view using removeFromSuperview its actually still active.